# Removing comments from web.config on build

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web.config-transform

Is it possible to remove the commented lines from a web.config on build? 
xml transform is fine to remove some elements but I couldn't find any syntax to clean the comments from the file.

We are using TFS 2010 build server for our builds.

Comment: Why do you even want to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UPDATE: See actual and working answer below.

---

It's not possible to do with xml transformation.

But you can do it with your own console app or msbuild task.
See example code here [Remove XML comments using Visual Studio 2010 Web Config Transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958564/remove-xml-comments-using-visual-studio-2010-web-config-transformation)

Comment: Yes it possible, see correct answer below

Answer (score 11):

```
<add xdt:Transform="RemoveAll" xdt:Locator="XPath(//comment())" />
```

Put this node within the root node of your transform file. "XPath(//comment())" selects all XML comment nodes to delete.

Comment: I can confirm it works and this should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I wanted to remove dev comments from the config files before I published to the web site.  I wrote an app that will recursively remove comments from config files in the directory I specify on the command line.  The sample below assumes YourCommentRemover will do the same.

I included the comment remover project as part of my solution and referenced it in the web app I plan to deploy.  You can just add the executable as a reference if you want.  Since I didn't want the comment remover to get deployed, I added a task to delete it from the **bin** directory where it was being staged for deploy, `(ProjectDir)obj\$(Configuration)\Package\PackageTmp\`.

Open your project file in a text editor (You can right-click on the project file in the solution explorer and select 'Edit Project File').

Go to the very end of the project file and insert the following before `</Project>`:

```
<Target Name="BeforePublish" BeforeTargets="MSDeployPublish">
    <Exec Command="$(ProjectDir)bin\YourCommentRemover $(ProjectDir)obj\$(Configuration)\Package\PackageTmp" />
    <Exec Command="del $(ProjectDir)obj\$(Configuration)\Package\PackageTmp\bin\YourCommentRemover.*" />
</Target>
```

This target will run before any files are copied to the web application location on publish.